# No Response is received from openday light netconf testtool simulator

Tags: simulator, opendaylight, juniper

I have started open daylight netconf testtool with juniper yangs.I can able to login to the simulated device using ssh netconf session. But while sending any rpc requests, no response is received and displayed in termainal session and no error message is logged.How do i resolve this issue? how do i find which part is causing this?

Comment: You might have better luck posting to the ODL netconf-dev mailing list.

Comment: I was getting the following error while running any rpc  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Hello message not received, instead received: &lt;rpc&gt;"
Is this can do some help?

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable in this area so I can't help. If you don't get answers here, I would suggest the netconf-dev mailing list.